# Can I add a hyperlink to my shape to close the current powerpoint presentation in C#

Tags: c#, hyperlink, powerpoint, office-addins

I have added a shape to my powerpoint add in and I would like to add a hyperlink to this shape which means that the current presentation will close when the shape is clicked.

So far I have:

```
PowerPoint.Shape shape = //my shape;
shape.ActionSettings[PowerPoint.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Hyperlink = ??
```

taken from [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.actionsetting.hyperlink(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shape.ActionSettings[PowerPoint.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Action = PowerPoint.PpActionType.ppActionEndShow;
```